# Working out the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In the question, the bivariate density is $f(x,y) = \frac{e^y}{e-2}$ is defined on the triangle $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$.

So far I've worked out the marginal distribution for $X$, $\frac{e^x-1}{e-2}$. I've also worked out the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, $\frac{e^y}{e^x-1}$ but I am not sure how the conditional distribution has $y$ in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated correctly. It's okay if the conditional distribution of $Y$ has $y$s in it.

Comment: were I to randomly generate values to calculate the empirical mean of $Y$,in R how would I do it then? I'm guessing I could have a distribution of $X$ using the marginal distribution but I'm stuck as to how to integrate the distribution of $y$?

Comment: Random number generation is its own field of study, I don't think I can explain in a comment.

Comment: I'm just confused as to how I would generate random $Y$s using the conditional distribution? Or should I just use the marginal distribution?

Comment: To generate random $Y$s you should use the marginal distribution. To generate random $Y$s GIVEN that you know $X=x$, you should use the conditional distribution.

Comment: I think I get it now! Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble deriving the conditional mean I am doing $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{ye^y}{e^x -1} dy$ and I get $\frac{e^x(x-1)}{e^x -1}$, which returns negative values for the expected value.

Comment: @user20391 I get $\left[\dfrac{e^y(y-1)}{e^x-1} \right]_{y=0}^{y=x} = \dfrac{ e^x(x-1)+1 }{ e^x - 1 }$ .